# How to close window opened by window.open?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I close a window opened by window.open? Currently I have a reactjs app with a server side that handles OAuth.

The flow is like this:
1) user clicks button and open up a new window that redirects to server side (server side redirects to authentication service).
2) server side emits a socket io event to client side alongside the user information received after authentication is successful
3) window open by window.open() finally will be closed.

The related code is pasted below

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const {
    socket,
    provider
  } = this.props
  console.log('component did mount')

  socket.on(provider, user => { // Event listener
    // Window should be closed at this stage after listening to event.
    console.log(user)
    this.setState({
      user
    })
    this.props.addUser(user.name, 10)
  })
}

startAuth() {
  const {
    provider
  } = this.props

  const width = 600,
    height = 600
  const left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (width / 2)
  const top = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (height / 2)
  const url = `https://localhost:5000/${provider}`

  return window.open(url, '', // Open window to server side
    `toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, 
          scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=${width}, 
          height=${height}, top=${top}, left=${left}`
  )
}
```

I tried to do window.close() in socket.on() but it closes the wrong window, not the window opened by window.open(). I also tried to add window.close() at the server side after emitting the socket io event but that doesn't do anything as well. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You assign the `open()` to a variable, like `var newWindow  = open(yourURL);`... then it's like `newWindow.close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the opened window and call close on that.

```
const opened = startAuth();

opened.close();
```